# What does "constipación" mean?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

I know "estreñimiento" is constipation, but I've seen "constipación" defined as both constipation and the common cold. Which is correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the dictionary of RAE (Real Academia Española), that is considered the authority in the Spanish language, you can see the definition as:

```
[Constipación][1]

1. f. constipado.

constipación de vientre

1. f. Med. estreñimiento.
```

And from the first definition, the meaning of [constipado](https://dle.rae.es/constipado) is:

constipado
De constipar.

1. m. catarro.
2. m. resfriado (‖ destemple general del cuerpo).

So, from this we can see that constipación can mean estreñimiento, or catarro, resfriado.

Note: Edited to fix errors in previous answer.

Comment: https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/constipaci%C3%B3n says it means "a cold (sickness)." It looks like the RAE definition says it can mean "constipado" (which apparently is the common cold?) or estreñimiento.

Answer (score 4):

> The word *constipado* and the verb *constipar(se)* are used in Madrid -and some other areas of Spain influenced by the speech of Madrid¬- as equivalent to "cold". Other spanish speakers use these same word with the meaning of "constipation".

<sub>*Source [Etimología de Constipado](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?constipado#:%7E:text=La%20palabra%20constipado%20y%20el,atasco%22%20o%20%22estre%C3%B1imiento%22.)*</sub>

Personally, I have only heard the words *constipado* or *constipada* as a reference to cold only in Spain, never *constipación*. In the rest of the Spanish speaking countries *constipado/a* or *constipación* is constipation.

Answer (score 2):

**Cuestión**: ...he visto "estreñimiento" definido como estreñimiento y resfriado común. ¿Cuál es correcta?

---

**RAE - Estreñimiento y Constipar**

RAE

Estreñimiento

1. m. Acción y efecto de estreñir o estreñirse.

Constipar

Del lat. constipāre 'constreñir'.

1. tr. Cerrar y apretar los poros, impidiendo la transpiración.
2. prnl. acatarrarse.

https://dle.rae.es/constipar

---

**Estreñimiento. Concepto**

El estreñimiento  (del latín stringĕre, apretar, comprimir), es una afección en la cual la persona podría tener menos de tres evacuaciones a la semana; las heces son duras, secas o grumosas; la evacuación de las heces resulta difícil o dolorosa; o queda una sensación de que la evacuación no fue completa.

---

**Desigual Utilización del Término por Países**

- En el Sur de España que yo sepa no utilizamos la palabra "estreñido" como sinónimo de "Resfriado". Aquí se dice "Constipado", aunque la mayoría de las personas pronuncian "Costipado" ó "Costipao", para referirse a que se tiene un catarro, un destemple general del cuerpo, se ha cogido frío ó se ha resfriado un poco. Como digo, nunca se utiliza para estreñimiento.
- *Los argentinos definitivamente le confieren el significado de estreñimiento tanto a constipación como a estar constipado. Muy raramente lo califican como "de nariz" para referirse al resfriado ó la gripe*.
- En El Salvador, "constipado" se asocia única y exclusivamente con el catarro o la gripe.
- En México, constipado se refiere a tener la nariz tapada, obstruida, resfriado, no tiene ninguna relación con estreñimiento.

---

**Procedencia y el por qué de esa Interpretación de Estreñimiento y Resfriado Común, dentro de la misma Voz:**

- En el S. XV en España, "Constipación" venia a ser Estreñimiento, y "Constipado" Estreñido.
- En Inglaterra y Francia, la forma es, Constipation - Constipated, y era el mismo término "Constipación" y "Constipado", "Estreñimiento y Estreñido" que se utilizaba en España. En la actualidad en estos países, Inglaterra y Francia, se sigue manteniendo aquella primitiva acepción, sin embargo, en España península, el sentido de las palabras al final se desvirtuó, no así en otras partes del Imperio.
  Esto ocasiona actualmente para los Españoles en lenguaje normal, lo que habitualmente se conoce por "falso amigo", pues "Constipado" para Españoles significa "Resfriado" y para Ingleses y Franceses es "Estreñido".
- En España en el siglo XVIII, la palabra "Constipado", que no "Constipación", empezó a adquirir un nuevo significado como sinónimo de acatarrado o resfriado. El Padre Feijóo atribuye la causa de este cambio a la moda de la época en la Corte de Madrid, ya que se consideraba vulgar y rústico, decir "resfriado ó acatarrado", y por contra más fino "constipado".

Así, los dos formas que hasta ahora habían convivido con las acepciones habituales comunes a las de otros países, **constipado** y **constipación**  fueron adaptándose a la nueva situación provocada por la moda y adquiriendo significado desiguales;

- **Constipado** (como participio sustantivado) paso a ser sinónimo de resfriado. La idea de que algo estaba obstruido, en este caso la nariz, facilitó el paso del concepto de estreñido a resfriado, (Lo assí cerrado de poros).

RAE - **Constipado** - De constipar.

1. m. catarro.
2. m. resfriado (‖ destemple general del cuerpo).

- Mientras, el sustantivo **Constipación**, en recuerdo de su antiguo significado, se restringió al ámbito del estómago y bajo vientre, para entenderse como estreñimiento, pero también mantuvo de manera ambivalentemente y extraña, quizás algo forzada, la referencia al constipado como (constipación de vientre), de ahí esas dos acepciones que parecen confusas.

RAE - **Constipación**

Del lat. tardío constipatio, -ōnis 'concentración'.

1. f. constipado.

constipación de vientre

1. f. Med. estreñimiento.

(La Constipación del Vientre es el estreñimiento)

---

Lo evolución de todo lo anterior dio como resultado que el Verbo "Constipar" tuviera las siguientes dos acepciones, pues antes solo incluía la primera;

**Constipar**

Del lat. constipāre 'constreñir'.

1. tr. Cerrar y apretar los poros, impidiendo la transpiración.

(*Que viene a recordarnos aquella primera definición del Diccionario de autoridades, 1726-1739 para hacer referencia al **estreñimiento**, cuando dice;*

*Los humores que criamos,*

*y en el estómago son,*

*si assientan en el hondón,*

***constipación** lo llamamos)*

2. prnl. **Acatarrarse**.

**Puede que de aquí venga tu confusión y entender "estreñimiento y resfriado", dentro de una misma voz "constipar", utilizada principalmente como "acatarrarse" en España y otros países iberoamericanos, pero igualmente empleada, de forma distinta,

"**estar constipado**",  sinónimo de "**estar estreñido**", en países como Argentina, Chile, Cuba, Uruguay, Bolivia, Venezuela...  aunque haya sido difícil llegar a esta observación.**

---

**La Respuesta** si cabe alguna, es que conociendo ya el por qué de estas distintas interpretaciones y su historia, lo más lógico, es utilizar el término "Constipado", con el significado que más se represente en el país o región donde esta expresión sea la más hablada.

Por último, tener en cuenta que puede ser un "falso amigo", en el caso de Españoles y otros países que usen el término como sinónimo de "resfriado", ya que si el término "Constipado" es utilizado por estos, en Francia ó Inglaterra u otros países de América, lo interpretarán como "Estreñimiento". Espero te haya ayudado a aclarar términos e ideas.

Answer (score 2):

According to DLE (Diccionario de la Lengua española) **constipado** is:

> 1. m. catarro.
> 2. m. resfriado (‖ destemple general del cuerpo).

If we search for the **resfriado** definition:

> 1. m. Enfriamiento o catarro.

And, if we look for the translation of **common cold** on the **Cambridge Dictionary**:

> resfriado común

---

**Referencias**

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles-espanol/the-common-cold?q=common+cold

Answer (score 1):

It is a common mistake to confuse the words 'constipado' and 'costipado'.
Constipado, is when you have problems passing stool, and Costipado, is when you have the flu

Comment: Aunque es habitual oírla en esta forma, 'costipado' es una expresión incorrecta, y por ello no aceptada en el Diccionario de la lengua. La forma correcta es 'constipado'. Ver https://dle.rae.es/constipado.